# Why {{variable_name}} to display JSON answer in HTML page using AngularJS does not work?

Tags: angularjs, json

I do not manage to display a JSON file. My sources are here:

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/XW78SuILkiCvk3uiZPUK?p=catalogue
```

and the answer is:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2luvlypscvls6rm/Screen%20Shot%202018-12-28%20at%2010.36.08%20AM.png?dl=0.
```

Basically, when I access http://localhost:8080/MANeUveR-webui/ index.html displays page1.html. The user enters some data and by clicking Next goes to page2.html where he add again some data. After pressing Submit a Json file is sent to another component (see app.js -> $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/re/z3', data, {headers:headers}).) which returns a list of JSONs. I'm interested only in the first JSON (see app.js -> app.controller("resultsController" ... -> $scope.greeting = $routeParams.jsonData[0];). As one can see from the dropbox link the answer is received and displayed via console.log. The issue is when displaying in the outputOffers.html

The code in outputOffers.html is simply:

```
<p>id: {{greeting.id}} </p>
<p>clockspeed: {{greeting.offer.clockSpeed}} </p>
```

I'm wondering if this is enough.

Comment: what is g here? can you post the JSON object?

Comment: There was I typo, I fixed it. A snippet from the JSON is: {"id": 1, "components": ["ssss"], "offer": {"appliesTo": [], "clockSpeed": "2.3 GHz", "currentGeneration": "Yes", "dedicatedEbsThroughput": "12000 Mbps", "description": "$4.888 per Dedicated Linux h1.16xlarge Instance Hour", "ecu": "188", "enhancedNetworkingSupported": "Yes", "instanceFamily": "Storage optimized", "instanceType": "h1.16xlarge", "licenseModel": "No License required", "location": "EU (Ireland)"}}. It is obtained from Python like this (variable res): import json res = json.dumps(build_response(...))
return res

Comment: Did you know that you can edit your question? This would be better than posting this additional information as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it as follows,

```
<p>clockspeed: {{greeting.offer["clockSpeed"]}} </p>
```

Comment: It displays this: clockspeed: {{greeting.offer["clockSpeed"]}}; the same issue as before.

Comment: do you see any errors in console? did you add ng-controller for the html?

Comment: I have no error in the console. I don't know exactly what you mean by "add ng-controller for the html" (I'm new to AngularJS). My code is here https://plnkr.co/edit/XW78SuILkiCvk3uiZPUK?p=catalogue , would be great if you could have a look.

Comment: you need to add ng-controller= "resultsController"  as you did for other 2 pages